# make /etc/profile take effect permanently

Tags: bash, etc

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables
https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=automatically%20source%20%2fetc%2fprofile

Probably a duplicated question.
I am using ubuntu.
use tmux in terminal. when I run `source /etc/profile` then I open another tab via  click the plus sign icon( in screen above,left corner). in the new tab(not sure it's new session or not)

I need to run `source /etc/profile` again to make certain things works (like shell promopt)

Comment: Did you make changes to `/etc/profile` that you want to take effect, before you started `tmux`? Is there still an issue if you open a new terminal that runs a login shell, or if you logout and log in again?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Environments are *copied* from the process that started your bash process. Unless you can convince that *immediate* parent process to all your new bashes to change its environment, it's impossible to make new shells have the new environment.